# How can I draw on procedural textures?

Tags: node-editor, transparency, image, texture-painting, shader-nodes

I try to combine procedural textures with an Image Texture via a mix node, so I can draw on my model.

But I can not find a way, so my procedural texture does not change in its brightness or contrast.

Is there a way to add draw on it and keep the Image texture transparent, except those parts where I'm painting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mix your procedural texture with your *Image Texture* in a *Color > Mix Color* node, plug the *Alpha* output of the *Image Texture* in the *Factor* input of the *Mix Color*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @moonboots